# Why is my SharePoint people search WorkEmail property blank?

Tags: sharepoint, search

I have an SSP setup for my site and I am trying to get the presence bubble working correctly. However, I cannot get the people search core results webpart to display the workemail.

I have output the raw xml into my people search core results xslt *and* used the SharePoint Query Web Service Test Tool to try and find values for these properties, but they are appearing blank (including sipAddress and HighConfidenceDisplayProperty11).

Note: The presence bubble does work when hard coded to users email address, so the problem is absolutely to do with the search results.

Answer (score 1):

Nat - the first thing I would check would be that the Metadata property mappings in the SSP/Search Admin area are setup properly.

For HighConfidenceDisplayProperty11 it should be set to People:WorkEmail(Text)

For SIPAddress it should be People:SPS-SipAddress(Text)

Make sure in the user profile properties that these are mapped to the proper AD fields.

Also make sure that the profile policies are setup so that "everyone" can view the properties you are looking at.

When you view a users profile page, does the work email or SIP show up there? What about if you go to edit your own profile?

Comment: Yes you are correct, those are the first things I checked.

Comment: I assume this means the properties show up in the profile pages as well?